# C# how to speed this up?

Tags: c#, xna

```
chunk_indices.AddRange(new int[6] { 0 + length, 1 + length, 2 + length, 3 + length, 2 + length, 1 + length });
```

It seems to run pretty slowly and takes about 1 microsecond which is a long time considering how many times I'm calling it, how can I make it faster?

Comment: I'm not really into C#, but '0 + length' seems kinda pointless.

Comment: Well you could obmit the `0 +`... The more interesting question is why you need that.

Comment: Care to give a little more context (e.g. the type of chunk_indices; if you wrote AddRange(), then its source etc.)? Also, do you absolutely need to create a new array here?

Comment: Are you sure this is the bottleneck in your algorithm? 1 microsecond is *really* fast.

Comment: Ahh, yeah the 0 + length is kind of pointless.  chunk_indices is just a list of ints.  I think I need to create a new array because length is different every time.  I used ANTS Performance Profile 7 and it's the slowest thing in the function I'm calling.

Comment: The `0 +` is optimized away by the compiler.

Comment: Ahh, my bad it's not the indices bit which is slowing it down :/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AddRange` is handy if you have an array or another collection that you can transform into an array to start with; however, here you could call `Add` repeatedly as well.

```
chunk_indices.Add(length);
chunk_indices.Add(length + 1);
chunk_indices.Add(length + 2);
chunk_indices.Add(length + 3);
chunk_indices.Add(length + 2);
chunk_indices.Add(length + 1);
```

Comment: duplicate answer (dtb's answer)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is Array.Copy like this

```
int[] source =  new int[6] { 0 + length, 1 + length, 2 + length, 3 + length, 2 + length, 1 + length }); 
//
// Assuming the chunk_indices has 6 elements already allocated.
//
Array.Copy(source, chunk_indices, 6);
```

The internal implementation of AddRange calls Array.Copy or CopyTo normally. Therefore, it is impossible for AddRange to perform better than a plain Array.Copy.

Further research revelead another option, faster than previous one:

```
// Copy the first 24 bytes from source to chunk_indices
Buffer.BlockCopy(source, 0, chunk_indices, 0, 6 * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Also the source can be a static array to avoid the memory allocation each time.

Answer (score 0):

Generally AddRange method accepts parameter array so you can try

```
chunk_indices.AddRange(length, 1 + length, 2 + length, 3 + length, 2 + length, 1 + length);
```