# Why is this function so slow?

Tags: c#, xna

I can't seem to figure out why it's so slow so I was hoping someone else might know :/.  chunk_vertices and chunk_indices are lists.

```
    public void get_cube_at_position(int x, int y, int z,Color colour)
    {
        int length;
        if (y > y_size - 2)
        {
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(x, y + 1, z), colour));
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(1 + x, y + 1, z), colour));
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(x, y + 1, 1 + z), colour));
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(1 + x, y + 1, 1 + z), colour));
            length = chunk_vertices.Count - 4;
            chunk_indices.Add(0 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(1 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(2 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(3 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(2 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(1 + length);

        }
        else if (blocks[x, y + 1, z] == 0)
        {
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(x, y + 1, z), colour));
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(1 + x, y + 1, z), colour));
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(x, y + 1, 1 + z), colour));
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(1 + x, y + 1, 1 + z), colour));
            length = chunk_vertices.Count - 4;
            chunk_indices.Add(0 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(1 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(2 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(3 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(2 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(1 + length);

        }
        if ( y != 0 && blocks[x, y - 1, z] == 0)
        {
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(x, y, z), colour));
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(x, y, 1 + z), colour));
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(1 + x, y, z), colour));
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(1 + x, y, 1 + z), colour));
            length = chunk_vertices.Count - 4;
            chunk_indices.Add(0 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(1 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(2 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(3 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(2 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(1 + length);
        }
        if (x > x_size - 2)
        {
        }
        else if (blocks[x + 1, y, z] == 0)
        {
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(1 + x, y, z), colour));
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(1 + x, y, 1 + z), colour));
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(1 + x, 1 + y, z), colour));
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(1 + x, 1 + y, 1 + z), colour));
            length = chunk_vertices.Count - 4;
            chunk_indices.Add(0 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(1 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(2 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(3 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(2 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(1 + length);
        }
        if (x != 0 && blocks[x - 1, y, z] == 0)
        {
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(x, y, z), colour));
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(x, y + 1, z), colour));
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(x, y, 1 + z), colour));
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(x, y + 1, 1 + z), colour));
            length = chunk_vertices.Count - 4;
            chunk_indices.Add(0 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(1 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(2 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(3 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(2 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(1 + length);
        }
        if (z > z_size - 2)
        {
        }
        else if (blocks[x, y, z + 1] == 0)
        {
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(x, y, 1 + z), colour));
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(x, y + 1, 1 + z), colour));
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(1 + x, y, 1 + z), colour));
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(1 + x, y + 1, 1 + z), colour));
            length = chunk_vertices.Count - 4;
            chunk_indices.Add(0 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(1 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(2 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(3 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(2 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(1 + length);

        }
        if (z != 0 && blocks[x, y, z - 1] == 0)
        {
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(x, y, z), colour));
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(1 + x, y, z), colour));
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(x, y + 1, z), colour));
            chunk_vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(1 + x, y + 1, z), colour));
            length = chunk_vertices.Count - 4;
            chunk_indices.Add(0 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(1 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(2 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(3 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(2 + length);
            chunk_indices.Add(1 + length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Define "slow".  Slow compared to what?

Comment: Does it matter how the OP wants to define slow? Just look through the code and try to find possible optimizations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# how to speed this up?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547789/c-sharp-how-to-speed-this-up)

Comment: @Marlon: I'm not sure "optimize my code" is a great SO question...

Comment: Yes, writing this code must have taken a while.  Use a profiler.

Comment: How often is this code called? Have you run a profiler against it yet?

Comment: Profile it with sampling method if you believe it's consuming too much CPU.

Comment: The most I call it is about 150,000 times per second, I've tried using redgate performance profiler but I still can't find what's causing it to go slow, which is why I asked here :/.  I wasn't asking for you to optimize my code I was asking if I was doing any obviously slow things.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Obviously those types of questions don't belong on SO. But asking the OP to define how slow the code is for something that is obviously a game and requires a bit of performance... it's just a pointless question. The method is called at most ~150,000 a second. At this point it does not matter how "slow" the code is, but how "fast" it can be made.

Comment: VertexPositionColor and Vector3 seem like value types and could potentially be both structs. Are they?

Comment: @dtryon Yes, they're XNA built-in types. They are structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing you are doing *within* that method is inherently a slow operation.

There are some micro-optimisations you could do to shave off some time. But nothing substantial.

Things you might be doing to your lists *outside* this method could potentially cause the `Add` method to be considerably slower than it could be (like regularly recreating them with `new`).

But the real problem is likely to be that you are simply calling it 150000 times per second (as you mentioned in your comment). You should always mention stuff like this - as something that is fast in one context may be slow in another.

Additionally, one assumes you are loading the data this method generates onto the GPU - probably by copying it to a new array - at least once per frame. This is probably too often, and the real cause of the speed loss.

What you probably should be doing is generating all your vertex/index data at load time, and then only referencing it at draw time.

Or, if you need to modify the data as the game runs, figure out ways to call this method less often and touch less data when you do (eg: only regenerate when you have to, only regenerate modified data, etc).